# Password validator against a weak password list that may contain single characters

Tags: java, security, passwords, azure-security

**1.** There is a password-validating functionality in our product checking the entered phrase against a weak password list. The following method removes parts of the password that hit against this list:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;

private String removeContaining(final String passwd, final List<String> list) {
    String lpasswd = passwd.toLowerCase();
    for (final String element : list) {
        if (element != null) {
            lpasswd = StringUtils.remove(lpasswd, element.toLowerCase());  //removing the hits
        }
    }
    return lpasswd;
}
```

And then the rest is checked to compile with minimal length and other criteria. 
What would be the better way to refactor this method if the banned list may contain single characters?

So, for examples, if list contains "a" and "b", the entered password is "abc23b$aa" it will become "c23$". Or we should forbid our customers to put 1-letters words in such lists?

**2.** Having investigating this issue I found a description of Azure-password handling mechanism:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/concept-password-ban-bad#step-2-check-if-password-is-considered-banned
From the article:

> Each banned password that is found in a user’s password is given one
>   point. Each remaining unique character is given one point. A password
>   must be at least five (5) points for it to be accepted. For the next
>   two examples, let’s assume that Contoso is using Azure AD Password
>   Protection and has “contoso” on their custom list. Let’s also assume
>   that “blank” is on the global list.
>
> Example: a user changes their password to “C0ntos0Blank12”
>
> After normalization, this password becomes “contosoblank12”. The
>   matching process finds that this password contains two banned
>   passwords: contoso and blank. This password is then given a score:
>
> [contoso] + [blank] + [1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/concept-password-ban-bad#step-2-check-if-password-is-considered-banned) + [2] = 4 points Since this password is
>   under five (5) points, it will be rejected.

But if the dictionary contains "Contoso" and "cont" how the overall scoring would be calculated (matching against "contoso" or against "cont")?

Thanks.

Comment: check for the entire password.

Comment: Why would you forbid passwords that contain a specific sequence? To make it safe? then force the user to enter a 32 letter sentence to make it safe..

Comment: @Lino I meant to restict customers from putting single-characters in banned password list, like "a", "j" etc

Comment: This is counterproductive, it would forbid password phrases, which are actually much safer than simple passwords. I would avoid such complex rules completely, just check for a minimum length of the password and check **the whole input** against a list of the most used passwords.